# Regular Expression for apache weblog

Tags: java, regex, apache, talend

i've got the following entry of a apache log and i try to parse in talend with the regualar expression input component.

Failing Entry:

> 100.100.100.100 - - [02/Jun/2015:00:15:17 +0200] "GET /xxx/xxx/ HTTP/1.1" 301 - - "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"

Passing Entry:

> 100.100.100.100 - - [02/Jun/2015:00:15:17 +0200] "GET /xxx/xxx/ HTTP/1.1" 200 58835 - "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT
>   5.0)"

Im using the following regular expression for that:

```
("^([\\S.]+) (\\S+) (\\S+) \\[(\\d{2}/\\w{3}/\\d{4}):(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}) ([+\\-]\\d{4})\\] "
+"\"([A-Z]+) (.+?) (.+?)\\ (\\d{3}+) (\\S+) ?\"?([^\"]*)\"? ?\"?([^\"]*)\"? ")
```

Im processing the logfile with Talend and the program is always complaining about the "-" after 301 but in the regex it is defined as \S+. In my opinion there should be a problem for the program to pass that entry. Do you think it's a bug or am i missing something?

Kind regards

Comment: There are 2 '-', aren't there?

Comment: Yes but the second one should be covered by the followed expression or?

Comment: I think not. Next you are matching one or no space, then one or no quote.

Comment: But even when i cut the regex at the point where i extracted the byte code i got the error. when i change the - after 100 into a number like 0 he is extracting everything. I tried to add a second (\\S+) after (\\d{3}+) (\\S+), but even than i get the same result of not passing the "-"

Comment: try using www.rubular.com  with your both failing and qualifying logs in test string text area